# pypi package imports python file instead of package

Tags: python, pip, pypi

After `pip install package_name` from my recently uploaded pypi package
It imports python filename directly after installing,
I wanted to use like below

`import package_name` or `from package_name import python_file`

but this doesnt work instead this works
`import python_file` even package is installed name is `package_name`

pypi package name `package_name` and
My directory structure is below

- package_name

  - setup.py
  - folder1

    - python_file

In setup.py , i've used `package_dir={'': 'folder_1'}`

but even `import folder_1` or `from folder_1 import python_file`  didnt worked.

I tried if adding `__init__.py` inside `folder_1`, it didnt solved.

I've been following Mark Smith - Publish a (Perfect) Python Package on PyPI,
which told this way , but any idea what is happening, how can i solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you actual did is to tell python that the root folder is `folder_1`.

This is not what you want.

You just need to tell that `folder_1` (or actually replace it by package_name, see below) is a package and to declare it using:

`packages = {'folder1'}`.

Usually, people don't do it but let the function `find_packages()` to do the work for them by `packages=find_packages()`

In addition package folder should contain a `__init__.py`.

to conclude you need a folder structure like below and use `find_packages()`.

It is OK and even popular choice that the project name and it **single** main package have the same name.

- project_name

  - setup.py
  - package_name

    - __init__.py
    - python_file.py